# PhantomJS Passing variable to page.evaluate by reference

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, pass-by-reference

I've searched for 2 days but still no changes, i need to have `foo` variable by reference inside `page.evaluate` but seems impossible.

```
var foo = 42;

setInterval(function(){
      console.log('outer '+foo++);

},1000);

page.open(url, function() {

  var pe = page.evaluate(function(foo) {
     setInterval(function(){
          console.log('inner inner '+foo);
      },1000);
  },foo);
  setInterval(function(){
      console.log('inner '+foo);
  },1000);
}.bind(foo));
```

both outer and inner are updating but the `inner inner` foo is static.I also tried binding but it returns this error:

```
SyntaxError: Expected token ']'

  undefined:2 in evaluateJavaScript
  phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390 in evaluate
  phantomjs://code/foo.js:37
  :0
  phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:286 in _onPageOpenFinished
```

**Edit**:
Just found out that the function evaluate is a sandbox, I'm just curious if there is some way like message passing or IPC between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is some way like message passing or IPC between these two?

Indeed there is - `page.evaluate` can return a simple variable or serialized object to the outer context:

```
var value_from_sandbox = page.evaluate(function(){ return 42; });
```

You don't explicitly state it in your question, but from the code samples I take it you want to monitor some variable on a live page. It is possible:

```
page.open(url, function() {

    // Set interval function in PhantomJS scope 
    // that will extract a variable from the page once a second
    setInterval(function(){

        var foo = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
        }

        console.log(foo);

    }, 1000);

});
```

There is one more way to call "home" from sandbox: [`page.callPhantom`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html), but note that it was still marked as "experimental" in the docs.

Comment: My first objective was sending data from outside (of sanbox/evaluate) to inside in real-time, which is impossible. But with help of ur answer i think i could run the whole evaluate inside an `interval` block and send/receive data every time.

Comment: It's not *enirely* impossible... You could create your own event listeners for data changing on the page and then use `page.callPhantom` to send it back, but yes, page.evaluate + setInterval are far mor reliable.